# PATH variable set incorrectly

Tags: windows, environment-variables

My "PATH" Variable is set to some in the "MinGW" directory on my C:\, I don't know how this happened, probably me fiddling with my PC to get something working (This is before stackoverflow). Now, Eclipse cannot open!

Does this require a lot of fixing, or just something simple?

(Sorry if this is dupped. I tried my best to look for something that solves it.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to My Computer > Right click> Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced Tab > Environment Variables.

Here you can see the Path variable and modify it.

Comment: Path variable contains location to binaries (.exe file) you have in the system. Your issue looks like that you have an incorrect file included in Path variable. In Windows, Path variable is separated by semi colon (;). So, just copy all the text inside the path variable, paste it in a text editor, delete the text which has MinGW (from one semi-colon ; to next)

Comment: e.g. if your Path variable is C:/Python34;C:/MinGW; C:/ProgramFiles/MongDB; you just need to remove any text with MinGW from semi-colon to semi-colon. In this case, after removal of MinGW it would look like C:/Python34; C:/ProgramFiles/MongDB; Now paste the text back in the Environment Variables WIndow and save!

Comment: For more reference, look at this article: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: If you have accidentally deleted all the Path variable, have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/523688/deleted-path-environment-variable-how-to-restore